# Gerrit is not allowing to push the code

Tags: git, gerrit, egit

i have a git repository where i have create one project. There are already some existing projects which are working fine.

Now i want to push the code of this new project, i have added the gerrit change-id in the commit but still i am getting the following error when trying to push.
I am using egit( eclipse git) as a git client

```
 missing Change-Id in commit message footer
Processing changes: refs: 1
Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message footer

Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:
  gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 i054564@git.wdf.sap.corp:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
And then amend the commit:
  git commit --amend
```

Is there any configuration to be done when i added a new project to an existing git repo for gerrit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make some additional remarks to Marcelo's answer.

Suppose the commit history is `A-B-C-D`. C and D are your newly made commits. If either C or D has no change-id, the push is blocked. In this case, you need to rewrite the commit message of C and D(let's say neither have change-id) before another push.

Install the hook first as the error log says.

```
gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 i054564@git.wdf.sap.corp:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
```

Run `git log` to check the commits.

Rewrite the commit messages.

```
git reset B --hard
git cherry-pick C
git commit --amend
#simply save and quit
git cherry-pick D
git commit --amend
#simply save and quit.
```

If there is an existing change-id, you could delete the whole change-id line, save and quit so that commit-msg generates a new change-id. In some cases you may need it.

In order to automatically deploy the hook commit-msg for every clone, you could add this commit-msg into Git's [TEMPLATE DIRECTORY](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-init). After this copy, you could run `git init` in an existing repo as an alternative method of copying the commit-msg into it.

Since you are using Gerrit, I'd like to say more. A merge-commit does not provoke the hook commit-msg, so a local true merge won't have change-id either even if the hook has been deployed. This will block the push too. So don't use `git pull origin <branch>` to sync and update the local branch before a push. Either `git pull origin --rebase <branch>` or `git fetch origin <branch> && git rebase FETCH_HEAD` is better. This makes no merge commit in the local.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're trying to push more than one commit to Gerrit but only the last one has the Change-Id. When you push a commit to Gerrit, all parent commits that don't exist yet in Gerrit will be pushed too. Take a look at the Git log to check all commits that will be pushed.